# How can I avoid iphone safari first letter in caps

Tags: iphone, html, forms, safari, textinput

I am designing a small webpage targeted for the iPhone/iPod touch. I have a form that requires the user to enter a code. When you tap on the corresponding field, the iphone will automatically set the first letter to caps. Is there any way to avoid this? I want the whole field to be entered in small caps.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edit: use "none" instead of "off". On your webpage, all you need to do is set the autocapitalize property to off for your input field. So:

```
<input autocapitalize="none">
```

See the [Safari Web Content Guide: Designing Forms](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html) and [Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html)

Below is the answer I had before, which relates to native apps. Keeping around for anyone who's looking for that answer.

From the UITextField [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield)

> The appearance of the keyboard itself can be customized using the properties provided by the UITextInputTraits protocol. Text field objects implement this protocol and support the properties it defines. You can use these properties to specify the type of keyboard (ASCII, Numbers, URL, Email, and others) to display. You can also configure the basic text entry behavior of the keyboard, such as whether it supports automatic capitalization and correction of the text.

So basically, the UITextField supports this protocol. The property needed is the autocapitalizationType. An example in code is:

```
myUITextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

or if you dislike the dot notation:

```
[myUITextField setAutocapitilizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
```

Comment: Ah dang. Just read the whole 'webpage' part. This doesn't really apply does it?

Answer (score 0):

For other input types, there are attributes available that do what they say:

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```