# How to prevent auto-capitalization in iOS Safari input tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ipad

I'm making a website with a login site where people can do different things.
When using an iPad to login the first letter in the password is auto set to uppercase, how do I change it so that the first letter is not uppercase, but standard lowercase or whatever they enter??

Comment: But if user wants that password starts with upper letter?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580793/how-can-i-avoid-iphone-safari-first-letter-in-caps

Comment: @Reniuz quote: "...or whatever they enter"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="password" ... autocapitalize="off">
```

This is straight from apple:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/mobile/userExperience/_index.html

Edit:

try just adding the autocapitalize tag to your asp:textbox, see if that works.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbPassWord" runat="server" TextMode="Password" autocapitalize="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside your input tag ([found in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580793/how-can-i-avoid-iphone-safari-first-letter-in-caps)):

```
autocapitalize="off"
```

Note: If you are not using pure HTML (just noticed the ASP.NET tag) you will need to add this as an html parameter somehow depending on what control style you are using.

I assume you already did this:

You need to specify your input box to be of type `"password"`.

```
<input type="password" name="password" />
```

I thought iOS Safari was smart enough to not do this for password tags, perhaps not though!

Comment: I'm using a textbox... <asp:TextBox ID="txbPassWord" runat="server"  TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox><br /> shouldn't that be enough??

Comment: @libertas that's what I reacted to as well. Quite odd. +1 from me anyway